# Android How can I convert String to Double without losing precision?

Tags: android, string, double

i want to develop one calculation base application but getting one problem.

Tried as below

```
double add_num = 10.06
String data = edittext.getText().toString();
```

value assign to data is

```
// data = 1000.06
```

now i am converting string to double

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(data);
// amount = 1000.0
double final_amount = amount + add_num;
// final_amount = 1010.0
```

getting final_amount is **1000.0** which is not correct because **amount** value is losing precision i want the correct answer which is **1000.06**

please let me know correct way without using format() method

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all correct value is `1010.12`, not `1000.06`. And this code:

```
double add_num = 10.06;

String value = "1000.06";
double amount = Double.parseDouble(value);

double final_amount = amount + add_num;    
System.out.println(final_amount);
```

prints `1010.1199999999999`, which is correct.

If you just want to print the number with the desired precision, use one of:

```
// Prints with two decimal places: "1010.12"
System.out.format("%.2f", final_amount);
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", final_amount));

// Example, set TextView text with two decimal places:
edittext.setText(String.format("%.2f", final_amount));
```

---

By the way, in your code you have:

```
String data = edittext.getText().toString();
double amount = Double.parseDouble(value); // value?
```

Shouldn't it be?

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use String.ValueOf(double d);
For Example:-
Double to String

```
String value=String.valueOf(1000.06);
```

OR

```
String value=String.valueOf(add_num);
```

String to Double

```
Double value=Double.valueOf("1000.06");
```

OR

```
Double value=Double.valueOf(add_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="1000.06";
double d=Double.parseDouble(s);
System.out.println(d);
```

The above code give output: **1000.06**